# Where to report a bug/feature for the Today scope of Ubuntu Touch?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, bug-reporting, scopes

The "Weather" section of the "Today" scope on my Ubuntu phone shows temperatures in Fahrenheit units. I am using the metric system and would like to see Celsius degrees. I suppose this is related to the current locale, but I don't want to change the language (English / US).

The "Weather" application has settings for changing the units, but the "Today" scope doesn't. Where can I make a request for this?

I searched Launchpad, and found these:

- https://bugs.launchpad.net/today-scope - is not configured to accept bugs (says *"Today Scope must be configured in order for Launchpad to forward bugs to the project's developers."*)
- https://launchpad.net/unity-scopes - "Today" doesn't appear in the "Projects" list

Comment: I had the same issue until some minutes ago. I cannot tell you, where to make a request for this to be changed, but I can give you a work-around, that will help you:
I have changed the display language to English - Canada, where the use the metric system. Now the scope gives me degrees Celsius.

Comment: The today scope is now open for bugs.. https://bugs.launchpad.net/today-scope

Comment: I've opened a bug report for this now: https://bugs.launchpad.net/today-scope/+bug/1476236

Answer (score 1):

I'm using the "Feedback" app:

https://appstore.bhdouglass.com/app/com.ubuntu.developer.nskaggs.feedback

You can find, and install it, from App Store.

BR.

Comment: It seems this is no longer available.